# Asynchronous function is not printing any output except for null

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm new to asynchronous code and I'm not quite sure why the code is not producing the expected output.

When the 'console.log(data.imdb_id)' is uncommented is prints the required ids one by one, but otherwise just prints a "null" from the 'console.log(err)' line.

How do I fill my promiseArray with the required values and return this array for later use?

```
var movie_ids = [
    474350, 522938, 540901,
    384018, 419704, 420818,
    521029, 301528, 484641,
    515195, 466272, 441282,
    423204, 533642, 530385,
    568012, 535544, 456740,
    523077, 531309
]

async function insert_ids(movie_ids) {

    var promiseArray = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= movie_ids.length; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var url1 = "FIRST PART";
            var url2 = "SECOND PART";

            request(url1 + movie_ids[i] + url2, function (err, res, body) {
                    if (!err & res.statusCode == 200) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(body);
                        resolve(data.imdb_id);
                        // console.log(data.imdb_id); > This prints the correct ids 
                    } else {
                        console.log(err); > Prints "null"
                    }
                });
        }));
    };

    await Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });

}

insert_ids(movie_ids);
```

Comment: Did you misspell `&&` as `&`? Your condition is not met when the `console.log(err)` is hit.

Comment: Also, your array indices are wrong. Your loop needs to be `for (var i = 0; i < movie_ids.length; i++)`